# Retrieve Contacts from Microsoft Exchange Server 2003

Tags: .net, exchange-server

How to retrieve contacts from Microsoft Exchange Server 2003 using .net?

Answer (score 1):

One way to access Exchange 2000-2003 is with webdav.

Here are a couple articles

- http://blogs.technet.com/kclemson/archive/2004/01/23/62247.aspx
- http://www.msexchange.org/articles/Access-Exchange-2000-2003-Mailbox-WebDAV.html

Also search stackoverflow for [webdav exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=webdav+exchange) for several other related questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

If this will run on a client machine, then you should try to program against the Outlook Object libraries. These are far easier than talking to Exchange 2003 itself.

If you need to run it without a client, or from a server, then your best option is to look into the Exchange 2003 WebDAV apis.